# How do I use a network printer?

Tags: cups

I have an Epson WiFi printer on my LAN that I would like to be able to send text to print.  However, everything says to install cups.

Problem.... Package cups is not available

```
$ sudo apt-get install cups
Reading package lists... Done Building
dependency tree Reading state information... Done Package cups is not
available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that
the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from
another source However the following packages replace it:  
cups-client cups-filters-core-drivers cups-filters
```

I install the cups-client, but I can't find any information of how to add my network printer.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! http://www.debianadmin.com/setup-cups-common-unix-printing-system-server-and-client-in-debian.html should help you.

Comment: What operating system you are using? On my `raspbian 2018-03-13` I find `cups/stable 2.2.1-8 armhf` and other cups stuff.

Comment: Fabian, thanks- I hadn't seen that site.  I'll give it a try.  (Yes, I know it's against the rules to say "thanks" on Stack Exchange).  Ingo- I am using Stretch on a Pi 3b.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem myself. The fix is simple: run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

And try to install cups again:

```
sudo apt-get cups
```

Comment: You should also do `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: Yes, that might also be necessary. Applying apt update to my answer.

Comment: *Update* is used to renew the package list. *Upgrading* the software on using an old package list doesn't make much sense. I have edited your answer on the assumption that you agree.

Comment: @Ingo, thanks. You are right, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which sets up CUPS to use a network printer on a clean installation of Unbutu Server 18.04 on Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

```bsh
## CUPS command line tools
sudo apt install cups-bsd
## CUPS system
sudo apt install cups

## confirm cups.service is running
sudo systemctl status cups

## find printers
##   -p show printers
##   -d show current default printer 
lpstat -p -d

# printer PRINTER_A is idle.  enabled since Thu Feb 18 22:13:10 2019
# printer PRINTER_B is idle.  enabled since Thu Feb 18 22:13:08 2019
# no system default destination

## set default printer
lpoptions -d PRINTER_B

## print some test file
lpr test-example.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one but as it came up in my search, I guess others are still finding it.

The usual way to configure cups is through the browser. Go to

localhost:631

You will need the password for 'pi' to have admin rights.